# Optimize PHP cURL and explode

Tags: php, optimization, curl, explode

I'm using PHP's cURL and explode methods to extract the upvotes from a Reddit post page remotely.

It's quite slow, it takes a number of seconds between the button click and the return of the data, my question is, how can I speed it up? Where can I optimize this? Is it slow in the cURL getting the URL or is it slow exploding the page?

Here's how I'm locating the upvote div and getting its contents:

```
function between($src, $start, $end){
    $txt = explode($start, $src);
    $txt2 = explode($end, $txt[1]);
    return trim($txt2[0]);
}

$title = between($data, '<div class="score unvoted">','</div>');
```

Here's the function I'm using to get the page data from Reddit.

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: It's probably the cURL that'a taking the majority of the time. Do some profiling using echo's with timestamps.

Comment: Profiling? Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Echo the time before you begin, then echo after you curl, and finally after exploding. Comparing these timestamps will tell you where most of the time is being spent.

Comment: If majority of time is being spent cURL'ing (as I suspect), you're most probably being limited by bandwidth and there's not much you can do. Fetching a remote page is a slow process.

Comment: @JacksonGariety you may try the IP address instead of domain name as a DNS lookup may take "some" time ...

Comment: You can't know how you can optimize until you know what you have to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into a profiling tool like [WebGrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind/) to see where the slow occurs directly.

Chances are it is cURL that's slowing down your page, but without profiling you cannot tell for certain.